# ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror, python-module

This is a question that has been asked severally, and trust me I have spent quite a lot of time going through a significant number of both the accepted and recommended solutions, and the scenarios in which the OP's have faced this challenge.

I have also invested some reading into the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports) regarding the same, but I feel very lost at this point. Here is what I have going on:

This is my directory structure:

```
├── api
│   ├── db_setup
│   │   ├── db_connect.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── model.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── routes
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── routes.py
```

I just need to import `db_connect.py` **into** `routes.py`

As you can see, there are `__init__.py` files in all the directories including the parent directory (suggested in most answers).

This is how I attempt the import in the `routes.py` file:

```
from flask import Flask
from ..db_setup import db_connect

app = Flask(__name__)
db = db_connect.start_database()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='localhost', port=8000)
```

This is the error I have been battling overnight

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Kindly note that all my `__init__.py` files **are blank**.

I will appreciate your help and guidance on what exactly I am doing wrong.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../db_setup'))
import db_connect
```

Comment: Hello @U12-Forward
Thanks for answering.

In my structure above, `db_setup` is the name of the folder, and `db_connect` is  the file I need.

Comment: I have tried it, this is what I get now: `File ".../api/routes/routes.py", line 2, in module> from db_setup import db_connect ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'db_setup'`

Comment: Where do I make the edits? I have added the code you suggested into routes.py but I still get the same error. Here is a link to my file: [link](https://snipboard.io/N16VOb.jpg)

Comment: @Anthony Change `from db_setup import db_connect` to just simply `import db_connect`

Comment: @ U12-Forward It doesn't seem to work either. [Take a look:](https://i.snipboard.io/1Pz5mv.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I also had lots of troubles with relative imports. The following works for me ONLY when executing routes.py while being inside the routes folder. If you can not do that, maybe you have to change your current working directory to the routes folder with `os.chwd("PATH")` or similar:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
from db_setup import db_connect

db_connect.some_function()
```